# How can I specify the referenced multitarget project's platform?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, msbuild, .net-standard

If I have a multi target (netstandard16 and PCL Profile44) project (new SDK style csproj) and I reference this in a Xamarin.iOS/Android project as project reference, how can I specify the referenced platform?

The Xamarin project pulls netstandard but I want to use the PCL in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overwrite the target framework in the project references using:

```
<ProjectReference Include="../other/other.csproj" AdditionalProperties="TargetFramework=your-pcl-TFM" />
```

Comment: This works for project references but as https://stackoverflow.com/users/738188/oren-novotny mentioned NuGet will choose the .NET Standard version. So I cannot create easily packages for now. I will investigate more and maybe https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/issues/194 Xamarin.Auth .NET Standard support will be out soon.

Comment: yes this only works for project references, NuGet has asset framework moniker fallbacks but they are dangerous to use

Answer (score 3):

You can't and NuGet won't either. Netstandard wins over legacy PCL, always. Why do you want the reverse?

Comment: I want to support both netstandard and PCL too, but I can't use Xamarin.Auth library only in PCL somehow. So I conditionally implement the functionality in PCL now but I cannot use it from the head project because it reference the netstandard version.